# Create a bootable recovery partition. (And related programs)

Tags: windows, partitioning, backup

I've searched for a while, and found many relevant topics, but none that actually answered my exact question.
I understand how to make a recovery partition, but how do you make it bootable? (Example: For HP, press F11 during startup to run recovery)

Also, what are some good programs for making recovery partitions? I've heard Norton PartitionMagic and Norton Ghost, or Acronis, but I'm not sure if there is something better (preferably free) for both creating partitions, and for making back-ups.

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

[DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) runs from within Windows and it can copy directly drive to drive or drive to image file.

[EASEUS Todo Backup](http://www.todo-backup.com/) is another such product.

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is an open-source imaging software that requires a boot CD.

Comment: Thanks for the list. Know of any way to make the image bootable from a partition (Without a disc)?

Comment: Try EasyBCD at http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1. Remember your backups!